# Creating LINQ statement against an EF Context with no relationships

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I cannot wrap my head around how to write a linq query against my EF context to get what I want.

**1) What I have**
Database with no foreign keys assigned, and a reverse engineered code first entity framework project.  I tried manually adding virtual classes so EF might create implied foreign keys in the DBcontext, but I get errors on my .Include statements still.

Without the include the only thing I can think of is to use left joins, but I haven't gotten it down yet.  In the end there will be 21 tables I have to get data from, but the following table outline encapsulates the majority of issues i'm facing.

Sample data structure:

*Table Human*: HumanId, LastFoodEatenId, FavoriteFoodId, CurrentlyDesiredFoodId

*Table Food*:  FoodId, FoodName, FoodStuff

*Table Toys*: HumanOwnerId, ToyId, ToyName

*Table Pets*: HumanOwnerId, PetId, PetName, PetType

*Table PetSurgery*: PetId, SurgeryId, SurgeryPerformed

**2) What I want**
Given a HumanID, I want a compsite class or something like it from a single query.

```
Public Class QueryResult
{
  public Human human {get;set;}
  public Food LastEatenFood {get;set;}
  public Food FavoriteFood {get;set;}
  public Food CurrentlyDesiredFood {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Toy> Toys {get;set;}
  public IEnumerable<Pet> Pets {get;set;} //Includes surgeries if any
}
```

Is it even possible to write a single query to get this kind of information in a single db hit?  I'd be fine is someone simply confirmed it is't possible.  Then I can at least request we add relationships to our database.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: "Database with no foreign keys assigned"

Come again? That's kinda like saying, "I can't get my windows to stop leaking air. By the way, I don't have a roof on my house." :)

Comment: Why dont you add the relations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use linq to query multiple, non-related tables.

I'm going to assume a LOT about your entities, but here we go...

```
int humanId = 1234;

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    var human = (from h in context.Humans
                 join lf in context.Foods on h.LastFoodEatenId equals lf.foodId into lfg
                 from lf in lfg.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
                 join ff in context.Foods on h.FavoriteFoodId equals lf.foodId into ffg
                 from ff in ffg.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
                 join cf in context.Foods on h.CurrentlyDesiredFoodId equals lf.foodId into cfg
                 from cf in cfg.DefaultIfEmpty() // left join
                 join p in context.Pets on h.humanId equals p.humanId into pg // group
                 join t in context.Toys on h.humanId equals t.humanId into tg // group
                 where h.humanId = humanId
                 select new QueryResult { human = h, LastEatenFood = lf, FavoriteFood = ff, CurrentlyDesiredFood = cf, Toys = tg, Pets = pg }
                 ).SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Note: I'm doing this from memory without a syntax checker, so ymmv. Adding surgeries should be possible as well, but may require a subquery.

Comment: I'm trying to set up mapping with fluent api as suggested below and that is not working so well right now.  I finally got around to testing your code and it worked!  I have a lot of tables to add in still, but I appreciate your help and effort.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: Using either the fluent configuration, or even better, having the foreign keys defined in the database are probably your best options. But sometimes those aren't available, so you can use linq do query your data whether relations are defined or not.

Comment: We did a left join by using DefaultIfEmpty for the foods, I'm curious why doesn't the groups need to do the same (toys and pets)?

Comment: Side note, with 23 joins the result is 2 times slower than simply hitting the database 23 times.  Hitting the database 23 times is 11 times slower than a single SQLCommand which returns a dataset.  It seems EF simply cannot compete.  I'm going to create a dummy database and add keys and see if I can get a competitive call.

Comment: @AdamHeeg when you group, collections are either empty or not, but they are not null, which is why you don't need DefaultOrEmpty(). As for the 23 joins, well, yes. Especially when you have multiple to many relationships, the dataset will become so massive that you will kill any performance, but that's typically a sign of a bigger problem...

Answer (score 1):

> I tried manually adding virtual classes

I assume you mean virtual *collections*. You can define relationships in a "code-first" model if they are not in the database. The only condition is that foreign keys must refer to properties that EF knows as primary keys. So you should be able to do LINQ queries using navigation properties in stead of these verbose joins by a model like this (reduced to the essentials):

```
class Human
{
    public int HumanId { get; set; }

    public int LastFoodEatenId { get; set; }
    public virtual Food LastEatenFood { get; set; }

    public int FavoriteFoodId { get; set; }
    public virtual Food FavoriteFood { get; set; }

    public int CurrentlyDesiredFoodId { get; set; }
    public virtual Food CurrentlyDesiredFood { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Toy> Toys { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Pet> Pets { get; set; }
}

class Food
{
    public int FoodId { get; set; }
}

class Pet
{
    public int PetId { get; set; }
    public int HumanOwnerId { get; set; }
}

class Toy
{
    public int ToyId { get; set; }
    public int HumanOwnerId { get; set; }
}
```

And a mapping:

```
class HumanMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Human>
{
    public HumanMapping()
    {
        HasOptional(h => h.LastEatenFood).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(h => h.LastFoodEatenId);
        HasOptional(h => h.FavoriteFood).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(h => h.FavoriteFoodId);
        HasOptional(h => h.CurrentlyDesiredFood).WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(h => h.CurrentlyDesiredFoodId);
        HasMany(h => h.Toys).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(t => t.HumanOwnerId);
        HasMany(h => h.Pets).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(t => t.HumanOwnerId);
    }
}
```

EF will infer the primary keys by name conventions.

Now you will be able to execute a LINQ statement like:

```
context.Humans.Where(h => h.HumanId == id)
       .Include(h => h.LastEatenFood)
       .Include(h => h.FavoriteFood)
       .Include(h => h.CurrentlyDesiredFood)
       .Include(h => h.Toys)
       .Include(h => h.Pets)
```

From your description I understand that `PetSurgery` should be a junction class between `Pet` and another class (`Surgery`?). Anyway, I think you will manage creating the correct mappings, seeing this example.

Comment: I'm getting errors on all my includes right now.  They are throwing a 'does not declare a navigation property with the name...'.  This error is being thrown on all 5 relationships.  I tried moving the HasOption into the OnModelCreating method - I saw that in other posts - but the error is the same.  I'm looking for more examples, but if you have any insight I'm all eyes.  Thank you.

Comment: I'd need to see your code to analyze that. The error 'does not declare...` tells that `Human` doesn't have the property mentioned in the `Include`, but is has... I assume you map the `Human` class as shown above to the table `Human`?

Comment: I used the power tool to generate code first from existing database.  From that I tried 2 different things.  First in the HumanMap class I added the code you showed above.  Next I went into the OnModelCreating method and added modelBuilder.Entity<Human>().HasOptional<Food>(f => f.LastFoodEaten).WithMany().HasForeignKey(lf = > lf.LastFoodEatenID);  With that code I still get an error A specified Include path is not valid...

Comment: Hmmm, weird, I've done exactly the same thing in the past and got a query with joins by using `Include`. You seem to have done everything right.

Comment: I have two relationships working now.  In my model builder I added a HasKey for the Food class and that seemed to fix the issue.  I'm going to now go about adding the other 19 relationships as best I can and see if we can get a decent response time.  I really wish EF was faster than what i'm seeing so far.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Good to hear that! I'm surprised EF doesn't infer the primary keys by naming conventions, but then, your model is probably different. There are a few ways to make EF a bit faster, but overall it's not build for speed.Any ORM is a compromise between performance and maintainable code (plus time to market).